# How to get Wi-Fi/LAN working in Recovery Mode?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, restore, recovery

I want to reinstall macOS on my MacBook. But when it says "To download and restore macOS, your computer's eligibility will be verified with Apple" it doesn't proceed though I have pressed *Continue*.

Then I realized that the Mac isn't connected to any Wi-Fi network. Attaching an Ethernet cable doesn't work either.

What can I do now? I have no backup. I need to either restore or proceed installation.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The clue is in your ScreenCap.

The recovery partition does not have your WiFi password stored so you will have to reconnect to WiFi "manually."

Select "Join Other Network..." and pick your WiFi network and enter the correct password. That should get you going.

Comment: I have teied but unfortunately wifi signal shows. But before installing os i have used wifi smoothly.